# How to pass user information to other page in Django 3.0?

Tags: django, authentication

I am new Django i am creating a simple login page and wants to redirect to home page with user info as soon as user clicks login button in login form user should be redirected to the home page with username

```
def login1(req):
     if req.method == 'POST':
        user = ppl.objects.filter(username = req.POST['text'])
        print(req.POST['text'])

        pwd = ppl.objects.filter(pwd = req.POST['pass'])
        print(req.POST['pass'])


       if user and pwd:
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home', {'u':user}))
       else:
           return render(req,'login.html',{'error':"username and password does not match"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
      auth.login(request, user)
      return redirect('home')
    else:
      return redirect('login')
  else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

And in your home page template or any other template you can call `{{ request.user.username }}` to see the current logged in user

Comment: i am using custom model over here so authenticate will work?

Comment: user returns 'None' .i think django is considering User model but currently i am using model named 'ppl'

Comment: if you defined a custom user model you should mention it in settings file. AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.YourCustomUser'

Comment: ohh tell me how can i do that?

Comment: add what i mention above in your settings file, pointing towards your custom user model

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'ppl' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'  i am getting this error

Comment: thank you ,u can see files over here https://github.com/swankhede/swan